# Multi Level ExpandleListView ? Android

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

Hi i need a list like this right now im using expandlelist but i dont know how to get sub lists under the main like i need. V is just to show drop arrow

Title V
Question V
Answer
Answer
Answer
Question V
Answer
Answer
Answer

Title V
Question V
Answer
Answer
Answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Three Level ListView in ExpandableListView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880281/how-to-add-three-level-listview-in-expandablelistview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Was implementing such thing, was using `AnimatedExpandableListView` was done with one adapter that recreates itself recursively.

you need data:

```
private HashMap<CategoryModel, List<CategoryModel>> mMainMenuExpandableList; // this is hashmap for categories;
```

this is your constructor for adapter:

```
public CategoriesExpandableListAdapter(Context context, HashMap<CategoryModel, List<CategoryModel>> hashMap, int parentCategoryId, int paddingLevel){ //... parent category is category from which start adapter (you search for it and init adapter according it, padding level i used to make padding from left for sub categories)
```

okay now:

you need 2 views for sub categories one is final that has no sub categories and another is one that contains also `AnimatedExpandableListView` which you init with created another adapter for it in on create view holder. I was set this list visibility to gone, and display it only when user tapped on it, with custom dropdown animation applied.

here is sample of item with expandable list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com..........customModels.TextViewMedium
            android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="test text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_folder_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_folder_right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_rightarow"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_divider"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_divider"
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_expandable_sublist_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com..........customModels.AnimatedExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_expandable_sublist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/divider"
            android:childDivider="@color/divider"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:background="@color/layouts_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is sample of final item (without subcats):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_folder_right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_rightarow"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com...........customModels.TextViewMedium
            android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="test text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it's not easy to implement but final result works like a charm ))

Comment: so aside from the xml this would be the code for the adapter right ?

Comment: this is items for expandable recyclerview