# Mutlilevel expandable listview

Tags: android

How to parse below json in multilevel expandable listview Any idea or suggesstion is appreciated.

```
 {
        "Company": {
            "HR Dept.": [],
            "Admin": [],
            "Technology": [
                {
                    "T_NAME": "TEAM1",
                    "T_MEMBERS": [
                        "XYZ",
                        "PQR"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "T_NAME": "TEAM2",
                    "T_MEMBERS": [
                        "STU",
                        "WXY"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "T_NAME": "TEAM3",
                    "T_MEMBERS": [
                        "ABC",
                        "DEF",
                        "GHI"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: [check](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/02/android-expandable-listview-json-http.html)

Comment: thanks for link but
My problem is like
Company
->HR
  Admin
  Tecnology
  ->team1
    ->members
  ->team2
    ->members

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880281/how-to-add-three-level-listview-in-expandablelistview-in-android/ then apply to your app although it's simpler